# Apache mod_rewrite Returning Bad Request in WAMPServer

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, wamp, wampserver

I'm running Windows 7 64 bit with WAMPServer 2.1. The version of Apache running is 2.2.17. I'm trying to set up a simple rewrite rule in `httpd.conf`:

```
<IfModule rewrite_module>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [PT,QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

I've gotten simpler RewriteRules to work previously, without regex, rewrite expressions, and the like. It seems that at this point, however, I'm getting a `400 Bad Request` error whenever attempting to visit any URL when this rule is active. The Apache log file gives these errors whenever this happens:

```
[Sat Feb 26 10:24:18 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Invalid URI in request GET /index.php HTTP/1.1
[Sat Feb 26 10:24:21 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Invalid URI in request GET / HTTP/1.1
```

The first error I tried hitting `localhost/index.php`. The second I just tried `localhost`.

Furthermore, even when I had the simpler rule working, the `RewriteCond` lines didn't seem to be working: static existing files such as style.css were being rerouted anyway.

Enabling RewriteLogging just seems to crash Apache, which appears to be a [documented issue on 64-bit machines running Windows 7](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=49155). Any ideas as to what the problem may be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two issues here that are likely contributing to your troubles. First, you can't check for file existence so easily in a server context (as you are with httpd.conf), because the request hasn't been mapped to the file system yet.

If your requests for static resources happen to correspond directly to your file system structure beyond your DOCUMENT_ROOT, you can solve this by appending the value of DOCUMENT_ROOT before the incoming REQUEST_URI, as follows:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
```

If the path to your static resources is transformed somewhere down the line, the [mod_rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) suggests using the following, which will issue a subrequest to perform a lookahead based on the request URI:

```
RewriteCond %{LA-U:REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{LA-U:REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

This approach is more expensive though, so try to use the first one where at all possible.

Secondly, the URI that you pass back into the request is actually invalid, because it needs the leading slash. Correcting that and combining it with the new conditions above gives you this modified rule set:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php?page=$0 [PT,QSA,L]
```

Note that the value of `page` here will always have a leading slash, so you might actually want to use this rule instead, depending on your handling logic in index.php:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /index.php?page=$1 [PT,QSA,L]
```

Comment: This appeared to be the issue. In addition, I ended up having to use the modified rewrite rule you have at the bottom (with the `/` in the matching regex) as the other pattern was still giving me 400 Bad Request errors from the browser (and Invalid Get in the apache log).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the

RewriteBase /your_directory

variable?

Comment: Yes. RewriteBase causes Apache to not start up at all with the error `RewriteBase: only valid in per-directory config files` (I'm using httpd.conf).